# Forcefully erase Raspberry Pi 2 micro SD card

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I foolishly rolled back my firmware so that I could install MySQL, because some tutorial told me to do so. I am usually good about not messing up that bad.

Anyway, once I rolled back my firmware, I rebooted my Pi and it only showed the rainbow splash screen for a second, then the screen turns off. I waited for the entire night and nothing happened. I Googled it, and most articles said reinstall Raspbian. I decided I needed to start over and reinstall Raspbian on the SD card, and at that point I hit the second problem. The SD is recognizable by OS X and Kali linux, but it is read-only, therefore not allowing me to use DD, gparted, fdisk, or Disk Utility to erase the SD card. I tried using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/theindentifierofthesdcard bs=somenumber`, regardless of what OS I was on, it still said "Permission Denied". I also tried `sudo chown -hR username /dev/SDIdentifier`, yet it still didn't help.

I used this command to roll back my Pi:
`sudo rpi-update f6eef32dd6388c3b04dbf462bd324d93281bf397`
and I got that command from this site: http://raspipress.com/2014/06/tutorial-install-mysql-server-on-raspbian/

This SD card is 64GB and was not cheap, I refuse to purchase a new one.

My question(s) is/are this:

1. Is there a way I can boot the Pi past the Splash screen and run sudo rpi-update to fix the firmware issue?
2. Is there a way I can totally erase the micro SD card so I can install Raspbian again?

Specs:
Raspberry Pi 2

64GB SanDisk Ultra Micro SD

My OSs:

Kali Linux

Mac OS X 10.11.3

I have Windows 10 as well, but didn't try it.

Comment: if you want to reset it anway, why don't you just format it and load a fresh image?

Comment: @dube , that's just my problem, it won't let me format it

Comment: How do you insert the microSD into your Mac?

Comment: Through an adapter to convert it to normal SD card size, then I plug it into another adapter in order to insert it into my Mac Pro via USB. That isn't the problem, cause I've tried it on multiple computers

Comment: Try it on Windows.

Comment: @PandaLion98 I did try to reformat it using the software **Milliways** suggested but it still told me that it was Write-Protected

Comment: @Ryan Try to format it on a camera on an old Nokia (where apps use .sis instead of .apk. Symbian. I'm talking about Symbian).

Comment: @PandaLion98 to be honest I don't know what .sis or .apk are and also I've left the age of actual cameras. I only have the ones built into iPhones, iPads and such

Comment: Not being able to erase an SD card is not really a pi related issue.  You seem to be saying you cannot write anything to it no matter what the data is or what hardware or OS you use.  I recommend you try our larger sibling [Super User](http://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: Hey now that you mentioned it, I couldn't format my Sandisk 64 GB sdcard yesterday on an old eeepc. It reported a success but it didnt do anything. However, it worked fine on an other computer (using SD Formatter 4.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SD card has an internal flag which indicates it is RO, but this is not enforced - it is up to software to honour this (which most OS do).

Your best option is to download the formatter from the SD Foundation. See:- https://members.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/